# Expert Advisor won´t take trades

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, expert-advisor

I have a little project with an Expert Advisor coded for Metatrader 4. It is supposed to take a buy trade when the price closes at least 5 points above the daily price at 6 am and a sell trade when the price closes at least 5 points below the daily price. Trading time is set to 7.45 am to 11.30 am. It is not allowed to take two buy trades or two sell trades in a row. I believe I tried everything, but it just won´t take trades when I backtest it.  Hope someone can see the problem.

```
// Declare global variable to store daily opening price
double dailyOpen = 0.0;

// Define global variables for trading start and end times
datetime tradingStartTime = D'1970.01.01 07:45:00';
datetime tradingEndTime = D'1970.01.01 11:30:00';

// Define global variables for the buy and sell orders
int orderTicket = 0;
bool orderPlaced = false;
int orderType = 0; // 0: No trade, 1: Buy, -1: Sell

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert initialization function                                   |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit()
{
    // Calculate daily opening price on EA initialization
    dailyOpen = iOpen(Symbol(), PERIOD_D1, 0);

    // Your other initialization code goes here

    return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Expert tick function                                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()
{
    // Check if the current time is within the trading window
    datetime currentTime = TimeCurrent();
    if (currentTime < tradingStartTime || currentTime > tradingEndTime)
    {
        // Outside of trading hours, do not execute trading logic
        return;
    }

    // Get the 5-minute closing price
    double closePrice = iClose(Symbol(), PERIOD_M5, 0);

    // Check if a trade is already placed and open
    if (orderPlaced && OrderSelect(orderTicket, SELECT_BY_TICKET) && OrderSymbol() == Symbol())
    {
        // Check if the trade is closed
        if (OrderCloseTime() > 0)
        {
            // Trade is closed, reset orderPlaced and determine the next order type
            orderPlaced = false;
            orderType *= -1; // Alternate between buy (1) and sell (-1)
        }

        // No further logic needed if the trade is still open
        return;
    }

    // Buy condition: Price closes 5 points above the daily opening price at 6 AM
    if (TimeHour(currentTime) == 6 && closePrice > dailyOpen + 5 && !orderPlaced && orderType != -1)
    {
        // Place a buy order with take profit and stop loss
        orderTicket = OrderSend(Symbol(), OP_BUY, 1.0, Ask, 3, 0, 0, "Buy Order", 0, 10, Green);

        if (orderTicket > 0)
        {
            orderPlaced = true;
            orderType = 1; // Set order type to Buy
        }
    }

    // Sell condition: Price closes 5 points below the daily opening price at 6 AM
    if (TimeHour(currentTime) == 6 && closePrice < dailyOpen - 5 && !orderPlaced && orderType != 1)
    {
        // Place a sell order with take profit and stop loss
        orderTicket = OrderSend(Symbol(), OP_SELL, 1.0, Bid, 3, 0, 0, "Sell Order", 0, 10, Red);

        if (orderTicket > 0)
        {
            orderPlaced = true;
            orderType = -1; // Set order type to Sell
        }
    }

 
}
```

I am hoping someone can help me finish up my EA so I can backtest it.